# Kubuntu boot into earlier kernel - set it to default?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, virtualbox, kubuntu

I have Kubuntu installed in a VirtualBox (Windows host), but as of the latest updgrades it won't boot anymore.

I found an earlier kernel that works, though, and I want to set it to default.

-

**What I do**

When I boot, I press `shift` so as to see this:

[image]

I go to `Advanced options for Ubuntu`, to see:

[image]

and I wrote which one I want to boot. 
 It is the **6th**, counting the first at **0**.

--

On Kubuntu, I go to `/etc/default`, open `grub`, change `GRUB_DEFAULT` from `0` to `6`, then run `update-grub`.

But it still does not work when I reboot the virtual machine.